# Is it possible to schedule a devops pipeline to run powershell script on machines in a deployment group?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

I a looking to run a scheduled pipeline that executes a powershell script against machines configured in a deployment group.

So far I've only seen that I can use a "Run PowerShell on Target Machines" task or write the powershell script itself to target specific machines.

I'd rather somehow use the deployment group configuration because that is where we set up what machines apply to each environment.  Is there a way to run a powershell script against any machines in a deployment group?

Comment: Are you using classic GUI pipelines or YAML? Deployment group jobs are only available on GUI pipelines. In YAML syntax you should need environments.

Comment: @GeralexGR  our Build pipelines are yaml, our release pipelines are gui.  I'm not familiar with how environments work in YAML syntax

Comment: Attaching an environments tutorial https://blog.geralexgr.com/azure/target-multiple-environments-with-deployment-jobs-azure-devops